# Hide status bar during slash screen in cocos2d-x

Tags: c++, ios, cocos2d-x, statusbar

I am working on an app using cocos2d-x v2.2.3 for iOS (in C++) and currently trying to hide the status bar when the splash screen is being shown.

I have:

1) Added "View controller-based status bar appearance" -> NO to ios/Info.plist

2) Added setStatusBarHidden code to rootviewController (http://www.cocos2d-x.org/forums/6/topics/29675)

but none of them seem to work. Any ideas as to how I can get this to work? Currently using Xcode 5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set YES for this key in info.plist "UIStatusBarHidden"

If you want to hide or unhide after also then you have to follow bit different procedure for iOS 7

Answer (score 0):

Try This one It will Run perfectly..

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];

And in XIB set none option for the status bar.

Reference: [Hide the status bar on iPhone on a single view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8326804/hide-the-status-bar-on-iphone-on-a-single-view)